360 deg pointcloud of environment using intelreasense 435i
I have depth cameras on 4 side of robot . I want to make a single pointcloud message combining all the pointcloud messages from  4 cameras.
Later want to use so obtained 360 pointcloud view of environment to localize the robot .
Please help me with the part where I want to make 360 pointcloud view of the environment.
Thanks in advance

You can find some repo's that do what you want:

pointcloud_concatenate
pointcloud_merger

But mostly for ROS 1 and not ROS 2.
What you could do is use this package (ROS 1) as a guideline. And convert it to a ROS 2 package.
